# Verificar se variável double está vazia ou é númerica

Tags: c#, algoritmo, matemática

Como posso verificar se a variável **a, b ou c** não foram informadas, e, se caso não foram informadas retornar todo o código ?

Como posso fazer também para verificar se foi informado no console a letra "x" para a variável **A** e definir a mesma como double 1.00 ... Obrigado!

```
double a, b, c, x1, x2, delta;
String[] dados = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

a = double.Parse(dados[0]);
b = double.Parse(dados[1]);
c = double.Parse(dados[2]);
delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
```

Comment: Você está dizendo para verificar se as variáveis informadas em Bhaskara ou se elas não foram definidas no runtime?

Comment: Verificar se elas não foram dadas pelo utilizador no runtime

Comment: bom pela lógica são 5 variáveis que deve ser informada, correto? se dados não tiver 5 posições os dados não foram informados e se mesmo informado não estiverem certo também é outro problema, não seria mais lógico colocar um estrutura de repetição para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Na verdade são 3 variáveis **a, b e c**, as outras eu só declarei-as como double. Como eu posso fazer um laço de repetição para verificar se as **a, b e c** não foram informadas ? Comecei a programar em **C#** por agora.

Answer (score 2):

Simplesmente use o método [TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__) que converte uma `string` para um numero `double`, o primeiro parâmetro do método é a string a ser convertida e o segundo é o resultado em `double` equivalente ao primeiro parâmetro.

Veja o exemplo adaptado para o seu caso:

```
var valores = ReadLine().Split(' ');
if (double.TryParse(valores[0],  out var r1) && double.TryParse(valores[1],  out var r2) && double.TryParse(valores[2],  out var r3))
{
    WriteLine($"{r1} {r2} {r3}");
}
```

Também, não há necessidade de se preocupar com exceções, ele retorna falso caso a conversão falhe, e verdadeiro se for bem sucedida.

Agora, seu código modificado ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
var valores = ReadLine().Split(' ');
if (double.TryParse(valores[0],  out var a) && double.TryParse(valores[1],  out var b) && double.TryParse(valores[2],  out var c))
{
    double x1, x2;
    double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    WriteLine($"Delta: {delta}");
}
```

Entrada:

> 2 12 1.1

Saída:

> Delta: 135.2

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Khq4Mg).

## Edição

Retornar todo o código, acho que você quis dizer mudar o fluxo de execução do programa. Para este caso, você pode usar um loop.

Há muitas coisas que podem ser melhoradas no código abaixo, usei como ilustração:

```
public static void Main() {
    var loop = true;        
    do {            
        var valores = ReadLine().Split(' ');            
        if (valores.Length == 3) {                             
            if (double.TryParse(valores[0],  out var a) && 
                double.TryParse(valores[1],  out var b) && 
                double.TryParse(valores[2],  out var c)) {
                
                double x1, x2;
                double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
                WriteLine($"\n\nDelta: {delta}");
                loop = false;
            }
            else {                
                WriteLine("\nValores invalidos.\n");
            }
        }
        else { 
            WriteLine("\nQuantidade de parametros invalidos. Informe 3 parametros.\n");
        }
        
    } while (loop);                    
}
```

No exemplo usei o `do-while`, ele é executado pelo menos uma vez, diferente do `while` que pode ser executado zero ou mais vezes. A variável booleana `loop` indica a condição de parada do programa, quando for falso o programa sai do laço `while` e finaliza. Como estamos usando um vetor é necessário verificar se os índices são validos para não lançar uma exceção, verificamos em

```
if (valores.Length == 3) { ...
```

para três elementos.

Veja todo o código funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zrZVz9).

Comment: Não era muito bem isso, amigo. Eu gostaria que o console verificasse se o valor de a,b e c foram informados pelo utilizador, e se não foram, retornar para onde informa dnv que no caso é a main

Comment: @PLINIORODRIGUES  o console não verifica os valores, a classe `Console` serve para representar os dados de entrada e saída para o seu programa, o método `TrayParse` que tem a responsabilidade de verificar se os valores estão válidos. E não há como a chamada para função `main` ser executada mias de uma fez, ela é executa uma única vez. Se você quer que o programa solicite novamente os dados caso os mesmo forem inválidos, você precisa de um loop. Logo vou editar minha resposta e mostrar como ficaria.